# How can I read PDF comments done with Mac's Preview on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, pdf

I use Linux on my desktop and Mac Os X on my laptop. Mac's Preview easily allows to comment a pdf file and, e.g., Acrobat Reader allows to see those comments, but not to edit them.

So, I wonder if there is any PDF reader on Linux that allows you to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested that [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) can show these notes of a PDF file that was annotated using Mac Preview. The Okular version I tested was 0.16.5, which is a very old version from CentOS 7. You will very likely have a newer version than that. Okular can also add and save annotation in the PDF file.

Okular uses KDE libs but doesn’t require installing the full KDE desktop. It works very well on my CentOS 7 GNOME desktop. Most Linux distros should have it. For instance:

- On Ubuntu/Debian: sudo apt-get install okular
- On Fedora/CentOS: sudo yum install okular

Answer (score 0):

There is a [UNIX version](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=10&platform=unix) of Adobe Reader available.
You can also try [Foxit PDF reader under Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21969). It has Gold rating, so it should work fine.